# What do I name my file if the format is asked to be {firstname}_{lastname}.js?

Tags: filenames

Are the brackets just placeholders or should they be included with the filename?

john_doe.js  vs.  {john}_{doe}.js

Comment: Remove the brackets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its just a placeholder, file name should be john_doe.js